# Format special Character in Phoenix HTML Link

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I've got a special use case I need to format a Phoenix HTML link.The link can contain special characters like `:` and `*` . As an example - 
`CSVLOAD:*out:domain.org:call:4471`.

Using the conventional Phoenix `link` produces `/CSVLOAD%3A%2Aout%3Adomain.org%3Acall%3A4471` as the URL.

Please how can i correct this to have `/CSVLOAD:*out:domain.org:call:4471`

My router.ex

```
resources "/instances", InstanceController, except: [:index] do
    resources "/rating-profiles", Rater.RatingProfileController do
    end
end
```

Comment: Does the generated link not work?

Comment: Can you show which route in your `router.ex` file you are hoping to match?

Comment: The link should work just fine. `%3A` is `:` and `%2A` is `*`.

Comment: I've updated with my router.ex. @Dogbert, It works just fine, but does not appear to nice having those characters in the URL, hoping there was a way i could correct that. I remember using solving something similar with constraints in rails route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Phoenix's Router helper functions are too aggressive to escape HTML and they escape `:` and `/` as well.

```
iex(1)> post_path(MyApp.Endpoint, :show, "/CSVLOAD:*out:domain.org:call:4471")
"/posts/%2FCSVLOAD%3A%2Aout%3Adomain.org%3Acall%3A4471"
```

The `link` function in Phoenix Views is not so aggressive:

```
iex(2)> link("Foo", to: "/CSVLOAD:*out:domain.org:call:4471") |> safe_to_string |> IO.puts
<a href="/CSVLOAD:*out:domain.org:call:4471">Foo</a>
```

There are two workarounds I can think of:

1. Manually construct the URL and pass it to `link` as shown above instead of using the router helper functions like `post_path`.
2. Remove the escapes which are not strictly required and pass that to `link`:

   ```
   link "Foo", to: (post_path(...) |> URI.decode |> URI.encode)
   ```

   You can declare a helper function for this, e.g.

   ```
   def reencode(string), do: string |> URI.decode |> URI.encode
   ```

   And then use it:

   ```
   link "Foo", to: reencode(post_path(...))
   ```

Comment: Thank You. Eventually constructed the URL.